# How can I find the word starting at a specific character position and not word postion in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
Str="I love chocolate pudding"
pos=7
def getWordatPos(pos):
    xxx
```

I need to return the word at the pos 7 which is chocolate. Is there anyway to do that? I know it is easy if chocolate is at index 2 but I need it at the character position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try.

```
Str="I love chocolate pudding"
pos=7

ans=Str[pos:].split()[0]
```

---

Output

```
"chocolate"
```

`Str[pos:]` return `'chocolate pudding'`, Then I split them using `split` which return `['chocolate','pudding']` and I extracted 1st-word using indexing.

If `pos=8` the output would be `'hocolate'`.